# Sanitizing HTML from Form Input not working (symfony6.3 php 8.2)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, sanitization, symfony6

Trying to implement a form that sanitizes html input according to
https://symfony.com/doc/current/html_sanitizer.html#sanitizing-html-from-form-input
but I cannot make it work properly.
Here is my setup:

html_sanitizer.yaml

```yaml
framework:
    html_sanitizer:
        sanitizers:
            app.post_sanitizer:
                allow_safe_elements: true
                #allow_static_elements: true
                allow_relative_medias: true
                allowed_link_schemes: ['http', 'https', 'href']
                allow_relative_links: true
                allow_elements:
                    img: '*'
                    div: '*'
                    span: '*'
                    p: '*'
                    a: '*'
                    i: '*'
```

ActivityRichTextFormType.php

```php
class ActivityRichTextFormType extends AbstractType
{

    public function __construct(
        private readonly HtmlSanitizerInterface $appPostSanitizer,
    ) {
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        //$data1 = $options['data']->getContent();
        //$data1 = $this->appPostSanitizer->sanitize($data1);
        //$options['data']->setContent($data1);

        $builder->add('content', TextareaType::class,
            ['label' => '', 'empty_data' => '']
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => ActRichText::class,
            'sanitize_html' => true,
            'sanitizer' => 'app.post_sanitizer',
            'translation_domain' => false
        ]);
    }
}
```

entity field:

```php
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT , nullable: true)]
    #[Assert\Length(max: 2255)]
    private ?string $content = null;
```

then to test functionality I enter something like

```html
<h2>Testing html form</h2>
<script>// <![CDATA[
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){var ql=document.querySelectorAll('A[quiz],DIV[quiz]'); 
// ]]></script>
```

When I just use `'sanitize_html' => true, 'sanitizer' => 'app.post_sanitizer',` in the resolver, the html text does NOT get sanitized. i.e. the script tag is kept in the content.

As a temporary workaround I added a manual sanitizer:

```php
        $data1 = $options['data']->getContent();
        $data1 = $this->appPostSanitizer->sanitize($data1);
        $options['data']->setContent($data1);
```

when i remove comments and activate this workaround, the html DOES get sanitized and the script tag is removed.

Any hints why the `sanitize_html` in the `resolver` does not work?
Thanks!

**Update:**
Created a fresh new project to test this issue and uploaded it at
[github symfony-html-sanitizer](https://github.com/pok-git/symfony-html-sanitizer).
I used a Model instead of an Entity to simplify things if anyone would like to check it out.

Comment: What is "ActRichText::class"? For the symfony form integration it must be "`TextType` forms, or any form extending this type (such as TextareaType)". Is ActRichText and extension of TextType or perhaps another type? That might be the problem.

Comment: `ActRichText`  is the entity that has the field `$content `. Instead of listing the whole entity i only posted the 1 field used in the form.

Comment: Yes, but why are you declaring a type of `ArtRichText` in the options, when the entity type is Types:TEXT ? What happens if you omit: `data_class' => ActRichText::class,`?

Comment: @JasonOlson : i checked it, nothing changes if I omit it. I use it as it is suggested at https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes. As said in this page although not always necessary, it's generally a good idea to explicitly specify the data_class option.

Comment: Adding a manual sanitizer at the form type does not work that well either. My best option for now is to add a manual sanitizer at the controller inside the form isSubmitted isValid check.

Comment: I basically followed your examples and it works as documented, so my only guess is that there is something different between your code and the sample code in the documentation.

Comment: @JasonOlson : Maybe it would be something in the config or Autowiring? Note: I added an update with a github link at the question.

Answer (score -1):

$sanitizedInput = htmlspecialchars($_POST['inputField'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

echo htmlspecialchars($sanitizedInput, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

var cleanHTML = DOMPurify.sanitize(dirtyHTML);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).